# Squarefree integers and floor function, Möbius function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, mobius-function, mobius-inversion

On page 40, exercise 44 of *Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory* by Tenenbaum:

44. Show that any integer $n\ge1$ can be uniquely decomposed as $n = qm^2$ ,
    where $q$ is squarefree. Denote by $Q(x)$ the number of squarefree integers $q$ not exceeding $x$. Establish the formula:
    $$
    \lfloor x\rfloor=\sum_{m\leq\sqrt{x}}Q\left(\frac{x}{m^2}\right),\hspace{20pt} (1)
    $$
    We know that 
    $$
    Q(x)=\sum_{q\leq x}|\mu(q)|,\hspace{20pt} (2)
    $$
    How can we prove the above formula using

I found heuristically that
$$
Q(x)=\sum_{d\leq\sqrt{x}}\mu(d)\left\lfloor\frac{x}{d^2}\right\rfloor\hspace{20pt} (3)
$$

My question is

1. How can we prove (1), (3)?
2. How can we prove (1) $\Leftrightarrow$ (3)?

Answer (score 2):

For every $x$ let $S(x)$ be the set of positive square-free integers not exceding $x$.
Every positive integer $n\leq x$ can be written uniquely as $m^2q$ where $m\leq\sqrt n\leq\sqrt x$ and $q$ is square-free and not exceding $x/m^2$, that's:
$$\{n:1\leq n\leq x\}=\bigcup_{m\leq\sqrt x}\left\{m^2q:q\in S\left(\frac x{m^2}\right)\right\}$$
Consequently:
\begin{align}
\lfloor x\rfloor
&=|\{n:1\leq n\leq x\}|\\
&=\left|\bigcup_{m\leq\sqrt x}\left\{m^2q:q\in S\left(\frac x{m^2}\right)\right\}\right|\\
&=\sum_{m\leq\sqrt x}\left|\left\{m^2q:q\in S\left(\frac x{m^2}\right)\right\}\right|\\
&=\sum_{m\leq\sqrt x}\left|S\left(\frac x{m^2}\right)\right|\\
&=\sum_{m\leq\sqrt x}Q\left(\frac x{m^2}\right)\\
\end{align}
which proves $(1)$.
To prove $(1\implies 3)$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{d\leq\sqrt n}\mu(d)\left\lfloor\frac x{d^2}\right\rfloor
&=\sum_{d\leq\sqrt n}\mu(d)\sum_{m\leq\sqrt{x/d^2}}Q\left(\frac{x/d^2}{m^2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{d\leq\sqrt n}\sum_{md\leq\sqrt x}\mu(d)Q\left(\frac{x}{(md)^2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n\leq\sqrt x}\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)Q\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n\leq\sqrt x}Q\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right)\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\\
&=Q(x)
\end{align}